# How can I find out the most used 2 words combo in a block of text?

Tags: php, n-gram, word-frequency

How can I find out what the most common two words that I used right after each other are from a block of text? In other words is there a tool online or offline (or code) where I can copy and paste text and it outputs my most used two word frequency like:

From most used to least:

"the cat" 2.9%
"she said" 1.8%
"went to" 1.2%

Thanks

Comment: No it's not homework. It's for a project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 2):

1. Chunk up the text into two word pairs (use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to help you)

   - find the second index of a space, using strpos, and then substring between the beginning and the second space index to get the two word pair.
2. Add each pair to a map or set (the pair will be the key) and set the value (if it already exists in the map, increment the value
3. Once you have parsed the full text, calculate the percentages based on the size of the map/set and the value for each pair.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Codemwnci but could you please provide some php example code. Or if your not too busy I can pay you to create this simple script. Thanks

Comment: @Codemwnci: Might be easier to use `preg_split()` at stage 1 to get the words broken up.  Then step through from the second word, using the previous and current.

Comment: @Mark: This is a Question/Answer site, not a freelancer recruitment site.

Comment: @Mark: The problem is, this looks like homework - now that's not inherently bad.  But people will generally not "do it for you", but will point you in the right direction if you demonstrate you have thought about it and got stuck.

Comment: Hi Orbling, I'm not sure what you mean by homework. I need it for a project I'm currently working on. Unfortunately I don't know how to do the steps Codemwnci. I would love to pay someone a small monetary amount for this simple tast but it sounds like its against the website rules. But I appreciate your help.

Comment: +1, Its the exact method I was taking, apart from a lil regex

Answer (score 1):

This was fun, but i had a little go at it, this should get you started and should not be your answer.

This is basically grouping the words into 2's, indexing them into an array and incrementing the times there found, and finally converting into a percentage :)

```
$data = 'In the first centuries of typesetting, quotations were distinguished merely by indicating the speaker, and this can still be seen in some editions of the Bible. During the Renaissance, quotations were distinguished by setting in a typeface contrasting with the main body text (often Italic type with roman, or the other way round). Block quotations were set this way at full size and full measure.
Quotation marks were first cut in type during the middle of the sixteenth century, and were used copiously by some printers by the seventeenth. In Baroque and Romantic-period books, they could be repeated at the beginning of every line of a long quotation. When this practice was abandoned, the empty margin remained, leaving an indented block quotation';

//Clean The Data from un required chars!
$data = preg_replace("/[^\w]/"," ",$data);

$segments = explode(" ",$data);
$indexes = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($segments);$i++)
{
   if($i == 0)
   {
      continue;
   }

   if(trim($segments[$i - 1]) != "" && trim($segments[$i]) != "")
   {
      $key = trim($segments[$i - 1]) . " " . trim($segments[$i]);
      if(array_key_exists($key,$indexes))
      {
          $indexes[$key]["count"]++;
      }else
      {
          $indexes[$key] = array(
              'count' => 1,
              'words' => $key
          );
      }
   }
}

//Change to the percentage:
$total_double_words = count($segments);
foreach($indexes as $id => $set)
{
    $indexes[$id]['percentage'] = number_format((($set['count']/ $total_double_words) * 100),2) . "%";
}

var_dump($indexes);
```

You can see it live here: http://codepad.org/rcwpddW8

Comment: RobertPitt I really appreciate you taking the time out to write that. That was exactly what I was looking for. May God bless you.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as what I came up with. The only other thing I would suggest is to replace multiple spaces with single spaces (`$data = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/', ' ', $data);`). In your loop, if key $i or $i-1 is empty, you just skip the pair, there is probably a lot of word pairs you are missing due to adding one space for each punctuation (e.g. "foo, bar" would become "foo  bar" with two spaces between).

Comment: the preg_replace is better outside the loop as it performs the action on the whole context once, and the `$key = trim(...)` removes invisiable chars from left + right of each word, meaning that no word is followed by spaces, my code is not meant to be perfect but as an example.